# Balance Repeatability Sample or Population for SD

Tags: statistical-mechanics

A question for the masses about standard deviation (SD), selection of population vs sample in balance measurements.

Analytical balances are typically checked for repeatability by taking 10 weight measurements and finding the uncertainty by calculating standard deviation.

There are two forms of standard deviation: population and sample. Population divides the sum of differences squared by $n$; where as, sample divides sum of differences squared by $n-1$.

If I take 10 measurements of a standard weight, is this not the entire population? Or does the fact that I will repeat this test in the future make it a sample? I would typically select population in this case; however, most of the balance manufacturers I am reading are quoting $n-1$. What is the correct SD?

Comment: Use the sample standard deviation: your samples are not the putative entire population.

Comment: The "population of measurements" are the infinite number of measurements that could be made with the balance in the exact state that it is in at the moment. Of course that isn't practical. If you measure a sample for years there would be wear on the sample, electronic drift of the balance, weights on the balance would corrode and so forth. The notion is that your ten measurements would be a "sample" from the infinite number of possible measurements. // You have to be careful with "repeatability." The repeatability  of individual measurements is different than the repeatability of the mean.

Comment: First, please see my two comments following @Mathew Mahindaratne's answer. Then you might be interested in the pros and cons of the two sample standard deviations that are applicable when the population mean is unknown (which is typically the case): https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/416102/247352 . Bottom line: us chemists generally use the formula with the Bessel correction, i.e., the factor of 1/(N-1) before the summation sign, because it is less negatively biased than the other one and its square is an unbiased estimate of the population variance.

Answer (score 1):

[Standard Deviation Formulas in Maths is fun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation-formulas.html) is a nice article to review. It explains why we have use two different formulas to find standard deviation for the population and sample. However, I'd like to point out that your explanation of calculation is a bit off. The correct formula to calculate standard deviation is:

$$ \bbox[yellow,5px,border:2px solid red]
{
\sigma = \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i-\mu)^2\right)}\qquad (1)}$$

where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the population and $\mu$ is the Mean (the simple average) of the population of numbers:

$$\mu = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i$$

According to the *Math is Fun* website:

> To calculate the standard deviation of those numbers:
>
> 1. Work out the Mean (the simple average of the numbers)
> 2. Then for each number: subtract the Mean and square the result
> 3. Then work out the mean of those squared differences.
> 4. Take the square root of that.

The correct formula to calculate standard deviation of a sample is:

$$ \bbox[white,5px,border:2px solid blue]
{
s = \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\chi)^2\right)}\qquad (2)}$$

where $s$ is the standard deviation of the sample (say you choose $n$ numbers out of total of $N$ numbers population) and $\chi$ is the mean (the simple average) of the chosen numbers, hence: $$\chi = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$.

**Note:** In our old days when I was taking analytical chemistry, we were instructed to use equation (1), if the $N \gt 10$, but to use equation (2) whenever we have to deal with data where $N \lt 10$.

Comment: Several points. First, equation 2, with n instead of the Bessel correction n-1, is also a correct sample standard deviation. It is more negatively biased than equation 2, but has some statistically nice properties. Second, if the population is infinite, N i.i.d. samples are taken and $\mu$ happens to be known (which is unlikely) and $\sigma$ is unknown, then equation 1 can be used to give yet another sample standard deviation, i.e., the left hand side is "sigma hat". Finally, the 2012 QUAM is recommended for lots more info: https://www.eurachem.org/images/stories/Guides/pdf/QUAM2012_P1.pdf

Comment: @Ed V: Thanks for the valuable insight.

Comment: Three of the sample standard deviation definitions (and their pdfs and expectation values) are given here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/410311/247352 . Note that @Mathew Mahindaratne's equation 1 gives $\sigma$ if N is finite and each of the N elements is sampled. His equation 1 also gives an *estimate* of $\sigma$ if the conditions are as stated in my previous comment. Bottom line: use equation 2 unless there is good reason to do otherwise. And for large N, it won't make much difference anyway.

Comment: Thank you folks for the clarification.  Very good display of the equations and explanation of usage